# JitsiMeet conversion to BigBlueButton

Tags: react-native, jitsi, video-conferencing, bigbluebutton, jitsi-meet

In order to develop a mobile app for the web app, which is already made on my company's server (which is based on BigBlueButton platform), I have a requirement of connecting to BigBlueButton conference / room using [jitsi-meet code of react-native](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet). I tried modifying its config.js file somewhat like [this](https://filebin.net/9xa5an7ke0dhyctc/democonfig_2.js?t=b7px328x), as well as modifying the baseURL, and room url, with the one of my server, based on BigBlueButton platform, but still unable to make connection. Not sure, how to do that.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i've used jitsi and eployed on production, but what does blueButton means?

Comment: BigBlueButton is the similar platform for video conferencing. We are already having a web app based on BigBlueButton platform, which we wanted to convert to mobile app too, but unluckily, I was unable to find any BigBlueButton platform mobile app, thats why, tried to convert jitsi-meet as per the BigBlueButton platform.

Comment: I would not go this way, BBB has an api for meetings, I would use the https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video and vanilla BBB api